# How to use Index over multiple sheets Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have the formula, that I use to check if there are numbers in column I on the office sheet. Is there a way I can get this formula to check for column I on other sheets as well.
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Office!$B$2:$B$45,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(Office!$I$2:$I$45),ROW(Office!$I$1:$I$44),""),ROW(Office!B11))),"")`

I want the end result to look something like this, I want this to be the front sheet, so someone can easily see what needs to be purchased, or is expired:
[image]

Here is a copy of Office sheet, Kit 1 looks almost identical except it contains different items (same are the same). There are further sheets, look almost identical, except the item list. The item list, and number should be are listed in a look-up table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a subset of your data as a demonstration. I have two sheets:

1. Office
2. Kit 1

I have two Named Tables, placed respectively with their top-left corner in cell B2 on the sheets above:

1. office
2. kit_1

Select any cell in the Office table and use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range. In the Power Query Editor, click Use Home>Close & Load To and select "Only Create Connection".

[image]

Repeat this process to create a connection to every table in your workbook.

When you've done that, you should have a list of connections to all the tables in your workbook. Now use Data>Get & Transform Data>Get Data>Combine Queries>Append then move all of the connections to the right-hand-side of the dialog:

[image]

This will have created a single query that contains all of your tables. The one thing missing is that you need a new column for the table name for each row.

In the Power Query Editor, use Home>Query>Advanced Editor. My query initially looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({office,kit_1})
in
    Source
```

Edit the query definition so that each query name inside the braces {} above is replaced by something of the form:

```
Table.AddColumn(office,"TableName",each "Office")
```

Where the first parameter is the query name, the second parameter is the column name and the third parameter is the value you want in the table name column in the end result.

So, for my query, I have this:

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({Table.AddColumn(office,"TableName",each "office"), Table.AddColumn(kit_1,"TableName",each "kit 1")})
in
    Source
```

And the query now looks like this:

[image]

Since we're only interested in rows where the expiry date has passed or where the Need to purchase is less than zero, add a column using Add Column>General>Custom Column and use this definition:

```
if [Need to Purchase]<0 or [Expiry Date]<=DateTime.LocalNow() then "Show on front page" else "Don't show on front page"
```

Call the column Filter.

Then, in your data, filter that column to "Show on front page", then right-click the column and use Remove.

[image]

Now use Home>Close & Load to put the query result back into the workbook.

To keep the data on the front page refreshed, you can either manually right-click the final query result and use Refresh, or right-click the query in the Queries & Connections window and select Properties, then configure how and how often you want the front page to be refreshed:

[image]